# "When the Romans counted the entirety of their whole army, their sum was greater than the value of this."

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, calculation-puzzle

I came across this site and you all seem really smart so I was possibly hoping you could help me. I have this puzzle and I can't work it out, does anyone has a clue or answer?

> When the Romans counted the entirety of their whole army, their sum was greater than the value of this.

It is not my puzzle or I would know the answer.

It came from [here](https://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showpost.php?p=111915409&postcount=259). It's not a joke or a pun, it's a puzzle in an online game I play.

Comment: You'll need to tell us where the puzzle comes from -- there's a strict rule here that that's always needed for anything you didn't make yourself. Also, fair warning, I suspect (though I don't know the answer) that this may be as much joke or pun as puzzle...

Comment: (My apologies for the "off-topic" bit in the message about needing attribution; there's a technical limitation on what different reasons can appear in those messages. Your question isn't off topic, it just needs you to say where the puzzle comes from.)

Comment: Sure, sorry I wasn't aware. It came from here:

https://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=2058034466

Or to be more precise post 259 on this page https://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=2058034466&page=7

It's not a joke or a pun, a puzzle in an online game i play.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, but I've added a link to the specific forum post for convenience. There doesn't seem to be much for us to go on, but I'll tentatively vote to reopen, and maybe someone else will be able to parse it better than I can.

Comment: Reopened. May be worth noting that the puzzle comes from a computer game called "Silent Hill" (maybe one of a series? I don't know anything about computer games) and that in the game that message is found written in blood on a wall.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be related to an ongoing competitive online game

Comment: Rules for the game thread you’re in include: “2. Don't cheat: This is a game that relies heavily on the players having integrity. No PMing other players in the game, and **no chat about the game outside of this game thread and designated back forum threads.** No posting of any PMs from the game mod or referring to the content of them. No screen-shots, quoting from backroom threads or naming of rooms anyone may or may not have are permitted.” (emphasis added). Asking here seems against the spirit of the game, and in any event, contravenes our rule against questions from ongoing contests.

Comment: Based on the given information, the answer could be 0(zero), aa any army, when counted in its entirety is 1/unique and since 1 is greater than only possible value - 0, which Romans did not have a means to show/represent!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe would be worth a try to go for:

> Roman numerals - in text are: MCDIILMIMVLI
>  In this order it does not make sence, but maybe it is just a sum: MMMDCLLVIIII=3709

Comment: Redundant words (*eg* "entirety", "whole", "their") are adding just one letter to this Roman number so maybe.